# How To Change Image in Image Column dynamically in XamGrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, xamgrid

I am working on `WPF` Application and i am using `XamGrid`. i am binding data to item source and my `xamGrid` consist one `XamComboEditor` Column and other one is Image column. First time assigning data to item source its working perfect. But what i want is when user selects any item from `XamComboEditor` Image should also change based on `XamComboEditor` value on selection changed event.

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYBgW.jpg)

Comment: Copy your code from image here, and remove the image.

Comment: Do your classes and properties implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`? When you select an item in `XamComboEditor`, how do you try to change the Image? What part of the process can you identify as not functioning?